# How to install a Reporter plugin for QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I can not get the plugin Reporter or SimpleReport to run in 2.4 or 2.2.  The plugin manager in qgis says there is no metadata.txt.  This is obviously not true and is in there.  I have changed the minimumversion in the metadata file but no luck.  Is there a way to get around this to make the plugin work?  Or maybe there is another way to generate a report in Qgis?

Answer (score 1):

SimpleReports works fine for me. The plugin manager installs it without any issues. You can try downloading it manually and unzipping it into the plugin folder.